# 23 SPSS Auto Column adjustment

Tags: spss

I have a very remedial question regarding 23 SPSS software.  Question:  Columns in Variable View do no increase as character size increases nor does it save once I have increased the column size.  The instructional YouTube shows the columns auto increasing.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

The Data Editor column widths are controlled by the columns property, which does not adjust according to the variable type or format.  This is just a display issue: it has no effect on the actual values.

That property should be saved with the data and set to that specification when the file is reopened, but it only affects the DE display.